# Can I change my ChrUbuntu install over to Arch Linux on a Samsung XE500C21 Chromebook?

Tags: arch-linux, chrome-book, chrubuntu

I installed ChrUbuntu 12.04 on my Chromebook (Samsung XE500C21). Is there a way to swap my distro over to Arch ARM?

Failing that, is there an easy way to install Arch ARM on the SSD of one of these Chromebooks? Is my only option to build and sign my own kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only "easy" way to change distros on early model Chromebooks relies on borrowing the original ChromeOS kernel as described [here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/cr-48-chrome-notebook-developer-information/how-to-boot-ubuntu-on-a-cr-48). If you want a different kernel you will have to build and sign it yourself.

If you're willing to install ordinary x86 Arch you can put it together in a VM, partition the SSD and then copy the Arch partition over raw. The page linked above goes into detail about how to do this and sub in the ChromeOS kernel.

Best of luck!